# How to combine multiple rows in Oracle SQL (having multiple limitations)

Tags: oracle, obiee, string-aggregation

I need to combine multiple rows in Oracle SQL but have no access to LISTAGG or wm_concat (EVALUATE_AGGR disabled).

Note: I need this to work in Oracle OBIEE 11.1.1.9.

Grateful for any help or tips at all.

Comment: [Various techniques are shown here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques). The `sys_connect_by_path` one might be a place to start, as you are already ranking them.

Comment: Thanks. I have seen this but LISTAGG, wm_concat and COLLECT are not enabled, and I have no access to write my own functions.

Okay: maybe I can get sys_connect_by_path to work

Comment: @delica is this to go into a Direct Database Request in OBIEE? Or you're going to try and get it into the RPD?

Comment: @delica - that was the first thought: Try the `connect_by_path` approach.

Comment: @RobinMoffatt cannot use RPD or DDR. Whatever I use will have to be done through column formulas and/or subqueries.

Answer (score 3):

Ugh. I hate writing this as an Answer, but I found that the `sys_connect_by_path` solutions, both at Oracle-Base (see Alex Poole's comment) and on William Robertson's web site (quoted in the Oracle-Base article), are less than perfect, and this won't fit in a comment.

Oracle-Base link: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques#row_number
William Robertson web site: http://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/one-row.html

The solution on Oracle-Base uses two calls to `row_number()` when only one is needed, and it uses an aggregate query instead of `connect_by_isleaf`. Perhaps that's the solution originally posted by William, but his page currently has the better solution, using just one `row_number()` call and `connect_by_isleaf` instead of aggregation.

However, on William's page, he uses `ltrim()` without the argument that shows which character to trim, so in fact it has no effect. And he subtracts 1 from the value of `row_number()`, so in the result the first token in each comma-separated list is left out.

Here is the corrected solution - for reference; I claim no originality to any of this. The illustration is run on the `EMP` table in the standard `SCOTT` schema.

```
select deptno
     , ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(ename,','), ',') as name_list
from   ( select deptno
              , ename
              , row_number() over (partition by deptno order by ename) as seq
         from   emp )
where connect_by_isleaf = 1
connect by seq = prior seq + 1 and deptno = prior deptno
start with seq = 1;

DEPTNO  NAME_LIST
------  ------------------------------------
10      CLARK,KING,MILLER
20      ADAMS,FORD,JONES,SCOTT,SMITH
30      ALLEN,BLAKE,JAMES,MARTIN,TURNER,WARD
```

Comment: Good points. Now I check, I wrote that in 2004, and I have no idea what the `ltrim` or the `-1` are there for.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson - It's never too late to fix it! As you can see, people still go back to it (for a good reason: it's the right answer when one can't use more recent tools like LISTAGG).

Comment: Don't worry, I'll be copying your version :)

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to look it up and re-write the code to help me. I am not at work now so cannot try but will do so on Monday. Note that I cannot work either with RPD nor issue Direct Database Request, so whatever solution I use has to be done through column formulas, subqueries, filters etc. in OBIEE. @WilliamRobertson

Comment: Do you know how I could your code given such limitations?

Comment: @delica - sorry, I don't know OBIEE, and I don't know what "column formulas" are. If your front-end allows you to enter queries, give it a try. Of course, use your table and column names, not "emp" and "deptno" and "ename".

Comment: @mathguy right I understand. It does allow me to enter queries but it expects them in a certain format and parses them before they are passed to the database. So the the final query that is passed to the database often does not look like what I want it to be but I cannot edit it directly. Thanks again however. I will leave this open for a couple more days and will close it then, accepting your answer. Unless someone else chimes in.

Comment: @delica - did you try the `xmlagg` approach on the page mathguy linked to?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I just tried and the system again returns that the function is not defined by the administrator. It seems that I cannot use any of the proposed solutions and will have to stick to my terrible hack. Would you have any other suggestions, given the limitations, and looking at my code above?